# Wordpress featured images and media library thumbnail no longer displays

Tags: wordpress, image, media-library

I have a WordPress blog that is on a VPS. Everything has been working fine until today when I realised that my featured images are no longer displaying. I logged in to my dashboard, media library, and all the image thumbnails are no longer displaying properly.

Before this time, I had a little issue with my caching plugin (W3Total Cache), so I deactivated it, and my site continued to function normally. But now, no featured image is displayed all through the site. What amazes me is that inline images in a post are still displaying in the site. [See example](http://www.loggtv.tv/2015/11/24/whao-ty-bello-chops-off-her-signature-afro-peep-her-new-look/).

Now my site's [homepage](http://www.loggtv.tv) is just blank, because no featured images are displayed. As of today, images which I attached in the post are just seen as links, but if the link is clicked, it redirects to the image. Here are some of the things I've tried so far:

- I've run `df -h` ssh command to verify if my diskpace is full.
- I've restarted `mysql` server several times.
- I've manually downloaded wordpress .zip file, and upload to the site.
- I've automatically `reinstall` wordpress using `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/update-core.php`.
- I've switched to a default theme.
- I've tried some of the resources similar to this question here, but none of the proffered solutions resolved my issue.
- My permission settings for all the sub-directories under `wp-content` is `755`. I have also tried changing them to `775` and `777`.
  *. I've used the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to try to regenerate the thumbnails, but it returned an error `The error message was: The originally uploaded image file cannot be found at`, but when I view the image directly from my browser, it returns the image.
- I've also used the **WP Original Media Path** plugin to try and restore the media path (if it was messed up), but to no avail.
- I've deactivated all plugins too.
- I just checked my `wp_postmeta` table in my DB and it returned this error `wp_postmeta table is marked as crashed`

How do I rectify this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the source of your homepage has nothing in the main section:

```
<section class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
                                            </section> <!-- end article section -->
```

and also due to the last item in your question, I assume you have a database problem instead of missing files (which I think would throw some 404s in my browser instead).

[Do you have `WP_DEBUG_LOG`?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) If so, check `wp-content/debug.log` for errors. Be sure to launch phpMyAdmin and browse around the tables to see everything is good in there.

Use [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html) to confirm if tables are corrupted, and in that case use [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html) to try to fix them (maybe phpMyAdmin has those in its GUI, I'm not sure right now).

Comment: Well, I don't really know what happened, but when I did `CHECK` table in phpMyAdmin, it returned some errors in the `wp_postmeta` table: `check warning Table is marked as crashed and last repair failed` , `check warning 7 clients are using or haven't closed the table pr...`. And I did reload the site, and the images displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS -> Php Manager-> Php Extensions -> php_gd2.dll enable. refresh or restart the server it will work...

After long days try got this solution.